# Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ and let $H = \langle [4]\rangle $ be the subgroup generated by $4$. List all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/H$ and show that the quotient is cyclic.

I think I just have a lack of understanding of terminology here. I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/H$ just represents the left cosets of $H$, but since $H = \langle [4]\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $4$, what exactly does this mean?

I understand how to show that the quotient is cyclic too, here is my attempt:

If there is an element $a \in G$ such that $\langle a\rangle = G$, we say that G is a cyclic group. However, I don't think we necessarily need this here. From the first part of this question, if the order is prime, then by lagranges theorem, or rather a theorem in my book we have that $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/H$ is cyclic and we are done.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Comment: Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{20},+)$ and its subgroup $\langle [4]_{20} \rangle :=\{n [4]_{20}|n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. Note that $o([4]_{20})=5$ since $5[4]_{20}=[0]_{20}$. For Lagrange $\langle [4]_{20} \rangle \le \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ so it is cyclic and its order is clearly $5$. The order of the quotient group is $|\mathbb{Z}_{20}/\langle [4]_{20} \rangle|=4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic.  So you can get that the quotient is cyclic by considering the canonical projection.

The elements of the quotient are the equivalence classes of elements of $\Bbb Z_{20}$ that differ by multiples of $4$.

Since there are five elements in $\langle 4\rangle$, the quotient has order $4$.

Comment: What would the elements be explicitly though? How do we obtain them, or at least how do I go about obtaining them

Comment: We have, for instance, the residue class of $0$, consisting in $\bar0=\{0,4,8,12,16\}$, which happens to equal $\langle4\rangle$.  Then the one for $1$ is $\bar1=\{1,5,9,13,17\}$.  There are two more...  Note that this quotient is (isomorphic to) $\Bbb Z_4$.  The elements can thus be represented by $\{0,1,2,3\}$ (or their equivalence classes, as it were).  Notice that the cosets partition $\Bbb Z_{20}$.  That is, if we think of it, as is natural, as $\{0.1.2.\dots,19\}$ under addition $\bmod{20}$, each of the twenty elements is in exactly one coset.  .

Answer (score 3):

You can understand a quotient in many ways, the most geometric one (in the case of general groups) would be as a collapsing of the corresponding group in the Cayley Graph, but to return to a more algebraic side :
Here, $[4]$ is what is called a normal subgroup, that is, its left cosets are the same as his right ones, so $G/H$ is just the set of *cosets* of $H$. The cosets of a subgroup $H$ are the equivalence classes defined by $a \sim b \equiv aH = \{ ah | h \in H\} = bH$.  When you quotient by this subgroup, you take the set of all those cosets and give it the natural product $gHfH = gfH$ to make it a group. Now intuitively you want to divide your group among the ways your subgroup can be "translated" or moved around your group. Here you want to know how elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ behave under multiplication by $4$. However, for all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ you clearly have $(g + 4)H = gH$ thus you are doing "modulo 4" inside $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, that is $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/H$ is the set of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ that produce different subgroups when multiplied with $[4]$.You should have a good idea of what they are with the precedent remark. Now to show it is cyclic you should prove it is again isomorphic to a cyclic subgroup which will be easy once you have deduced what $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/H$ is.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to simply list the elements and do it from scratch:

$\mathbb Z_{20}=\{[0]=(0,20,\cdots),\ [1]=(1,21,\cdots),\cdots, [18]=(18,38,\cdots \ ),\ [19]=(19,39,\cdots \ )\}.$

And $[4]=(4,24,\cdots).$ Now, $\mathbb Z$ is Abelian, so the group operation is coset addition.

Then, since $[4]+[4]+[4]+[4]+[4]=[0]$ so $\langle [4]\rangle$ cyclic of order $5$.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more, I understand that you wrote them all out, but I'm not sure what's going on in the last line?

Comment: It's addition in the quotient group. Note that $[0]=[20]=[40],$ that is each of $0,20,40,$ etc is a representative of the $same$ coset, therefore the same element of the quotient group. And the LHS of the sum is $[20]$ and the RHS is $[0]$, so equality holds.

Comment: so is the order that you stated, the order of just K itself?